# Как ограничеть только одним окном в тоже время Example.exe сгенерированный "pyinstaller"?

Tags: python, tkinter

Я написал код для одной программы , потом я сгенерировал с помошью pypinstaller  программа.exe
Проблема в том что это программа.exe запускается 3 раз в тоже время  если нажимаю открыть 3 раза.
Подскажите пожайлуста  как ограничеть максимум 1 запуском в тоже время.

Код :

```
import os
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import scrolledtext
from future.builtins import int
import logging
from tkinter.tix import Shell
import subprocess, sys 
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
from distutils import command
import logging
import logging.config
from asyncio.tasks import sleep
from test.test_quopri import QuopriTestCase
from Tools.scripts.fixdiv import report



root= tk.Tk()

root.title("Autoloader_PSV5000")

canvas1 = tk.Canvas(root, width = 615, height = 515, bg = 'gray94', relief = 'raised')
canvas1.pack()


label1 = tk.Label(root, text='Scan please ', bg = 'gray90',font=('helvetica', 14))
canvas1.create_window(120, 50, window=label1)

label2 = tk.Label(root, text='Report window ', bg = 'gray90',font=('helvetica', 14))
canvas1.create_window(130, 150, window=label2)

entry1 = tk.Entry (root,width=54,bd=5,font=('helvetica', 12, 'bold'))
canvas1.create_window(310, 100, window=entry1)

report1 = tk.scrolledtext.ScrolledText(width=49,height=17,bd=5,state='disabled',font=('helvetica', 10, 'bold'))
canvas1.create_window(250,320,window=report1)


Pass = "| Status : PASSED |"
Fail = "| Status : FAILED |"


   


root.mainloop(0)
```

Answer (score 2):

Проверять запущен ли процесс, если запущен - что-то делать, если нет - продолжать выполнение.

```
import os
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import scrolledtext
from future.builtins import int
import logging
from tkinter.tix import Shell
import subprocess, sys 
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
from distutils import command
import logging
import logging.config
from asyncio.tasks import sleep
from test.test_quopri import QuopriTestCase
from Tools.scripts.fixdiv import report
import psutil

for proc in psutil.process_iter():
    name = proc.name()
    if name == "program.exe":
        pass


root= tk.Tk()
    
    #other_code
```

Comment: Это код работает в принцепе ,но я не знаю где поставить , где-то до открытея program.exe , потому что когда пытаюсь открыть программ , показывает что оно уже открыто

Comment: Что поставить? Вы знаете как называется Ваша программа? Вот подставьте это вместо program.exe

Comment: В самом начале кода

Comment: Изменил ответ, что бы было нагляднее

Comment: @KonstantinFedorov, смотрите в чем проблема: наш экзешник называется program.exe , мы его запускаем, и проверяем, запущен ли экзешник program.exe, и всегда получаем ответ, что уже запущен (т.к. мы его запустили из него же и делаем проверку). А нужно как-то проверить, что запущен другой экзешник с таким именем, и это не тот же процесс, из которого мы делаем проверку.

Answer (score 0):

Доброе время суток.

Я нашел решение и надеюсь кому-то поможет.

Изначальный код :

```
import os
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import scrolledtext
from future.builtins import int
import logging
from tkinter.tix import Shell
import subprocess, sys 
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
from distutils import command
import logging
import logging.config
from asyncio.tasks import sleep
from test.test_quopri import QuopriTestCase
from Tools.scripts.fixdiv import report



root= tk.Tk()

root.title("Autoloader_PSV5000")

canvas1 = tk.Canvas(root, width = 615, height = 515, bg = 'gray94', relief = 'raised')
canvas1.pack()


label1 = tk.Label(root, text='Scan please ', bg = 'gray90',font=('helvetica', 14))
canvas1.create_window(120, 50, window=label1)

label2 = tk.Label(root, text='Report window ', bg = 'gray90',font=('helvetica', 14))
canvas1.create_window(130, 150, window=label2)

entry1 = tk.Entry (root,width=54,bd=5,font=('helvetica', 12, 'bold'))
canvas1.create_window(310, 100, window=entry1)

report1 = tk.scrolledtext.ScrolledText(width=49,height=17,bd=5,state='disabled',font=('helvetica', 10, 'bold'))
canvas1.create_window(250,320,window=report1)


Pass = "| Status : PASSED |"
Fail = "| Status : FAILED |"


   


root.mainloop(0)
```

В библиотеке wx.Python есть такая команда "wx.SingleInstanceChecker()".
Оно проверяет, открыто ли ваше приложение.
Для этого я создал другой Frame только он невидемый и через этот Frame я проверяю!

Модифицированный код:

```
    import os
    from tkinter import *
    import tkinter as tk
    from tkinter import messagebox
    from tkinter import scrolledtext
    from future.builtins import int
    import logging
    from tkinter.tix import Shell
    import subprocess, sys 
    from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
    from distutils import command
    import logging
    import logging.config
    from asyncio.tasks import sleep
    from test.test_quopri import QuopriTestCase
    from Tools.scripts.fixdiv import report
    #Добавил нужные библиотеки 
    import wx
    import wx.lib.agw.genericmessagedialog as GMD
    
    root= tk.Tk()
    
    root.title("Autoloader_PSV5000")
    
    canvas1 = tk.Canvas(root, width = 615, height = 515, bg = 'gray94', relief = 'raised')
    canvas1.pack()
    
    
    label1 = tk.Label(root, text='Scan please ', bg = 'gray90',font=('helvetica', 14))
    canvas1.create_window(120, 50, window=label1)
    
    label2 = tk.Label(root, text='Report window ', bg = 'gray90',font=('helvetica', 14))
    canvas1.create_window(130, 150, window=label2)
    
    entry1 = tk.Entry (root,width=54,bd=5,font=('helvetica', 12, 'bold'))
    canvas1.create_window(310, 100, window=entry1)
    
    report1 = tk.scrolledtext.ScrolledText(width=49,height=17,bd=5,state='disabled',font=('helvetica', 10, 'bold'))
    canvas1.create_window(250,320,window=report1)
    
    
    Pass = "| Status : PASSED |"
    Fail = "| Status : FAILED |"
################################Создал Класс и  Фунцию##############################    
    class SingleAppFrame(wx.Frame):
        def __init__(self, parent, title):
            wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title="SingleApp", size=(1, 1))
            self.Centre()
     
    
    class SingleApp(wx.App):
        def OnInit(self):
            self.name = "SingleApp-%s" % wx.GetUserId()
            self.instance = wx.SingleInstanceChecker(self.name)
            if self.instance.IsAnotherRunning():
                #wx.MessageBox("Only one instance of Autoloader can be run at one time", "Autoloader_PSV5000",wx.OK | wx.ICON_ERROR)
                dlg=GMD.GenericMessageDialog(None,"Only one instance of Autoloader can be run at one time", "Autoloader_PSV5000",agwStyle=wx.ICON_EXCLAMATION| wx.OK)
                dlg.ShowModal()
                return False
            frame = SingleAppFrame(None, "SingleApp")
            frame.Show(False) ##### False = нивидемое ##############################
            return True
    
    
        
    app = SingleApp(redirect=False)
######################################################################################       
    
    
    root.mainloop(0)
```

[image: Фотография]

Comment: Тянуть еще wxpython только чтобы проверить, запущено ли приложение - это немного чересчур. Если вы все пакуете в один исполняемый файл, это очень сильно увеличит его размер.

Comment: Прердложите другой вариант , если это черезчур.